# Problem with formatting memory card

Tags: 12.04, usb, gparted, partitioning, format

I have memory card which I remove during a format on phone and is now not working.
In windows it is showing in Device manager as other devices and not showing in disk management.
I ubuntu 12.04 I tried various solution on internet. Now the current state is this..
Disk is mounting on ubuntu. When giving format on disk utility, it ends up in error 
"Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)".

I tried gparted utility. Before format we need to unmount the device. After I unmount it will do a scan again and the device is listed no more.
I was siting the last 5 hours on this. I don't care about the data, I just want the card to work. Someone please help..

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin, backup all your files just in case!

First, unplug and plug the card back in. Then, open a terminal and type the following command to list your device names:

```
df
```

These next two commands should give you similar results:

```
sudo blkid
```

and

```
lsblk
```

The device should be listed as /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1. It is important you use the proper device name (/dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1) in the following commands **or you will format and erase the wrong device**!!! Open a terminal and type the following commands (/dev/sdb1 is used here as an example but be aware that your device name may be different!)

example command:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

then,

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb1
```

Alternatively, you could use this command instead:

```
sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -v /dev/sdb1
```

Both of these commands format the drive to fat32. You will have to unplug and plug the device back in after you format to remount the device.